# Laravel livewire query string problems in Nginx, when use it as paginator

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a laravel project with Livewire Library installed, i have problems with query string parameter when i change from Apache to Nginx, the path is change to empty, in example the main path is http://example.com/active , when i use livewire for pagination it should http://example.com/active?page=1, but when i change the pagination to page 2 it change to http://example.com/?page=2 seems without path name, and when return to pagination page 1 the path is empty http://example.com/ but the page is still working.

I have No issue when using apache with standard config for laravel, but when i change to my production server and based to Nginx the path issues come up, but only in page that i'm using livewire library in page or for pagination, maybe people here have a same experience and problems, thanks in advance for any help.

Here my nginx config :

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name _;

   root /var/www/project/public;

   location / {
   
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME       $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx)? Specifically, I see nothing about `fastcgi_split_path_info` or `fastcgi_index` in there. You're also not including the rest of the fastcgi parameters, typically stored in another file.

Comment: Also what do you mean the URL changes? What URL are you outputting that is changed by the server?

Comment: I do exactly what the documentation said, but nothing change, what i mean is URL path + query_string as i mention above, i mean the the path in example http://example.com/subpath, the "subpath" path should be exist when i adding the query string with Livewire.js in example http://example.com/subpath?page=2 , the apps is working well but the "subpath" url is missing and directly point to http://example.com/?page=2.

Answer (score 0):

This is the config I use all the time (for development using Docker Compose) and it works, try mine and see if it works, then start deleting stuff until it stops working again:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.php;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

I think it might be the missing `include fastcgi_params;` or `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;`.

Comment: Thanks, i try your suggestion but seems its not working in my case, its weird when i'm using apache its appear as exactly output what i wanted, ie : http://example.com/subpath?page=3 , but when i move to nginx the url is become http://example.com/?page=3 without the word or sub-url "subpath" , but the apps is working well.

Comment: That is very strange, as my config is for local development and works.

Comment: Finnaly solved, the problems iswhen i adding `add_header` for csp and set to origin, Livewire isn't response well, anyway thank's so much for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `nginx` config file

```
location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf|woff2|woff|ttf|mp3|mp4|ogg|json|svg|css|js)$       
{       
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This worked for me after a long period of trying.

You can remove the extensions you don`t need.