# 404 when livewire is put in subfolder NGINX

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-8, nginx-config, laravel-livewire

I made laravel app using livewire and have tried it using NGINX all work normally. This is my initial config on NGINX

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

 # Log files for Debugging
 access_log /var/log/nginx/vhostlaravel-access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/vhostlaravel-error.log;

 # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
 root /home/nicholas/Downloads/tes/Strongbee-new-explore/public;
 #root /var/www/strongbee-web-3.0;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

 # Your Domain Name
 server_name nicholas.com;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
     location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

Then I want Laravel to be in a subfolder (explore) so https://nicholas.com/explore.
I tried this config, but getting 404 on my livewire
[View photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shHpA.png)

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

 # Log files for Debugging
 access_log /var/log/nginx/vhostlaravel-access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/vhostlaravel-error.log;

 # Webroot Directory for Laravel project
 #root /home/nicholas/Downloads/tes/Strongbee-new-explore/public;
 root /var/www/strongbee-web-3.0;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

 # Your Domain Name
 server_name nicholas.com;


    location ^~ /explore {
        alias /home/nicholas/Downloads/tes/Strongbee-new-explore/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @explore;
        location ~ \.php {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/nicholas/Downloads/tes/Strongbee-new-explore/public/index.php;
        }
    }

    location @explore {
        rewrite /explore/(.*)$ /explore/index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # PHP-FPM Configuration Nginx
     location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
```

}

I think there is a problem with the try_file on subfolder.
Please help me

This is my livewire.php

```
    <?php

use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Types\Null_;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Namespace
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the root namespace for Livewire component classes in
    | your application. This value affects component auto-discovery and
    | any Livewire file helper commands, like `artisan make:livewire`.
    |
    | After changing this item, run: `php artisan livewire:discover`.
    |
    */

    'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Livewire',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path for Livewire component views. This affects
    | file manipulation helper commands like `artisan make:livewire`.
    |
    */

    'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Layout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | The default layout view that will be used when rendering a component via
    | Route::get('/some-endpoint', SomeComponent::class);. In this case the
    | the view returned by SomeComponent will be wrapped in "layouts.app"
    |
    */

    'layout' => 'layouts.app',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Assets URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path to Livewire JavaScript assets, for cases where
    | your app's domain root is not the correct path. By default, Livewire
    | will load its JavaScript assets from the app's "relative root".
    |
    | Examples: "/assets", "myurl.com/app".
    |
    */

    'asset_url' => '/explorer',
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire App URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value should be used if livewire assets are served from CDN.
    | Livewire will communicate with an app through this url.
    |
    | Examples: "https://my-app.com", "myurl.com/app".
    |
    */

    'app_url' => NULL,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Endpoint Middleware Group
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the middleware group that will be applied to the main
    | Livewire "message" endpoint (the endpoint that gets hit everytime
    | a Livewire component updates). It is set to "web" by default.
    |
    */

    'middleware_group' => 'web',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Temporary File Uploads Endpoint Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Livewire handles file uploads by storing uploads in a temporary directory
    | before the file is validated and stored permanently. All file uploads
    | are directed to a global endpoint for temporary storage. The config
    | items below are used for customizing the way the endpoint works.
    |
    */

    'temporary_file_upload' => [
        'disk' => null,        // Example: 'local', 's3'              Default: 'default'
        'rules' => null,       // Example: ['file', 'mimes:png,jpg']  Default: ['required', 'file', 'max:12288'] (12MB)
        'directory' => null,   // Example: 'tmp'                      Default  'livewire-tmp'
        'middleware' => null,  // Example: 'throttle:5,1'             Default: 'throttle:60,1'
        'preview_mimes' => [   // Supported file types for temporary pre-signed file URLs.
            'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'svg', 'wav', 'mp4',
            'mov', 'avi', 'wmv', 'mp3', 'm4a',
            'jpg', 'jpeg', 'mpga', 'webp', 'wma',
        ],
        'max_upload_time' => 5, // Max duration (in minutes) before an upload gets invalidated.
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Manifest File Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value sets the path to the Livewire manifest file.
    | The default should work for most cases (which is
    | "<app_root>/bootstrap/cache/livewire-components.php"), but for specific
    | cases like when hosting on Laravel Vapor, it could be set to a different value.
    |
    | Example: for Laravel Vapor, it would be "/tmp/storage/bootstrap/cache/livewire-components.php".
    |
    */

    'manifest_path' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Back Button Cache
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines whether the back button cache will be used on pages
    | that contain Livewire. By disabling back button cache, it ensures that
    | the back button shows the correct state of components, instead of
    | potentially stale, cached data.
    |
    | Setting it to "false" (default) will disable back button cache.
    |
    */

    'back_button_cache' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Render On Redirect
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines whether Livewire will render before it's redirected
    | or not. Setting it to "false" (default) will mean the render method is
    | skipped when redirecting. And "true" will mean the render method is
    | run before redirecting. Browsers bfcache can store a potentially
    | stale view if render is skipped on redirect.
    |
    */

    'render_on_redirect' => false,

];
```

this is my .env

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:aZ59Hf9EfJfdqY8LQyCsqf9gGi9N6u6yn6uUboJHgmo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://nicholas.com/explorer

ASSET_URL = http://nicholas.com/explorer


API_BASE_URL = https://api.strongbee.tech


LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I get this problem quite often. I am 99% sure this is unrelated to nginx

Comment: This solution to your problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72962526/14635900

Answer (score 3):

## Configuring The Asset Base URL

By default, Livewire serves its JavaScript portion (livewire.js) from the following route in your app: `/livewire/livewire.js`.

The actual script tag that gets generated defaults to:
`<script src="/livewire/livewire.js"></script>`

There are two scenarios that will cause this default behavior to break:

You publish the Livewire assets and are now serving them from a sub-folder like `"assets"`.

Your app is hosted on a non-root path on your domain. For example: `https://your-laravel-app.com/application`. In this case, the actual assets will be served from `/application/livewire/livewire.js`, but the generated script tag, will be trying to fetch `/livewire/livewire.js`.

> To solve either of these issues, you can configure the `"asset_url"` in **`config/livewire.php`** to customize what's prepended to the `src=""` attribute.

For example, after publishing Livewire's config file, here are the settings that would fix the above two issues:

```php
'asset_url' => '/assets'
```

or

```php
'asset_url' => '/application'
```

see [official docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation#configuring-the-asset-base-url) for more info.

### Additional notes:

- I had my livewire routes cached, so `php artisan optimize` was needed to get rid of all 404's.

Comment: I think that's almost right. I tried like this, but still 404
https://ibb.co/0fvcz9h

https://ibb.co/q97CJXK

Can you help me??

Comment: @NicholasAntonius where are alot if things wrong :D https://ibb.co/0fvcz9h - makes no sense, you are just overwriting the asset url 2 times. You have to specify the one subfolder which matches your app `'asset_url' =>  '/explorer'`. If you get an iframe like in your second screenshot this is likely because you did not return a response object in your component/controller.

Comment: I Still have the same issue
Is there anything I need to set in the .env apat app.php section?

Comment: @NicholasAntonius can you update your question with your `config/livewire.php` ?

Comment: I already update my question

Comment: Seems correct to me. did you run `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: yap, but still same. 
this is the console https://ibb.co/0tgkTY2. Looks like this "et::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" has an effect

Comment: Can u please also show the structure of your `public` folder?

Comment: this is my public structur https://ibb.co/4YNQw08

Comment: @NicholasAntonius okay, so your css is in `public\css`. That should also be in your layout. I assume you have the path to your css fixed ? include the subfolder `css` there. or use `'/css/style.css'`.

`http://nicholas.com/explorer/style.css` should be `http://nicholas.com/explorer/css/style.css`

As for `[..]\assets\search.css` this simply does not exist in your `public` folder

Comment: I use like this asset('css/style.css')

Comment: Try with a `/` at the end: `ASSET_URL=http://nicholas.com/explorer/`

Comment: I don't think so. because on the console it looks like this
GET http://nicholas.com/explorer//assets/search.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: hmm. it seems your asset url is not resolving correcly. you could try using a relative path instead. Does `/css/style.css` work ?

Comment: style.css already fixed, but livewire stil post livewire/message 404

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what the browser tried to load:

```
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

Rendered:

```
    <script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=xxxxx" data-turbo-eval="false" data-turbolinks-eval="false" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `config/livewire.php` had the `asset_url` as:

```
'asset_url' => env('LIVEWIRE_ASSETS'),
```

`LIVEWIRE_ASSETS` didn't exist in the `.env` file, so I just needed to add the variable in the file:

```
LIVEWIRE_ASSETS=/sub_directory
```

Now the script loads correctly:

```
    <script src="/sub_directory/livewire/livewire.js?id=xxxxx" data-turbo-eval="false" data-turbolinks-eval="false" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```